# Is there way to query "url-pattern" property from Java code of servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Is there way to obtain "url-pattern" property from Java code of servlet filter ? I know I can pass same pattern in servlet init params but it seems redundant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In servlet 3.0 - yes:

```
public void init(FilterConfig cfg) {
   List<String> mappings = 
       cfg.getServletContext().getFilterRegistration(cfg.getFilterName())
          .getUrlPatternMappings();
}
```

Comment: apart from the one you mentioned - no (perhaps some container-specific classes, but I'd prefer the param)